# Prove that $m\tan (\theta-30°)=n\tan (\theta+120°)$

Tags: trigonometry

If $m\tan (\theta-30°)=n\tan (\theta+120°)$ then prove that :
$$\cos 2\theta=\frac{m+n}{2(m-n)}$$

My attempt\
Here,
$$m\tan (\theta-30°)=n\tan (\theta+120)$$
$$\frac{\tan (\theta-30°)}{\tan (\theta+120°)}=\frac{n}{m}$$.

Now, what should I do next?

Comment: Tan 120 = -tan 60

Comment: Are supplying all the homework, here?  Btw $$\dfrac{m-n}{m+n}$$ reminds me of https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/

Comment: Expand both the numerator and the denominator in terms of tan(a-B)

Comment: And remember cos 2A = 1-tan^2(A) / 1+ tan^2(A).

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829636/if-m-tan-theta-pi-6-n-tan-theta-2-pi-3-then-find-cos-2-theta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$m\tan (\theta-30^\circ)=n\tan (\theta+120^\circ)$$
$$\frac{\tan (\theta+120^\circ)}{\tan (\theta-30^\circ)}=\frac{m}{n}$$
Applying Componendo-Dividendo, we get
$$\frac{\tan (\theta+120^\circ)+\tan (\theta-30^\circ)}{\tan (\theta+120^\circ)-\tan (\theta-30^\circ)}=\frac{m+n}{m-n}$$

Now expand the L.H.S., keeping in mind that $\tan 30^\circ=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$ and $\tan 120^\circ=-\sqrt3$

As Lab suggested, you can go as follows:

$$\frac{\frac{\sin (\theta+120^\circ)}{\cos (\theta+120^\circ)}+\frac{\sin (\theta-30^\circ)}{\cos (\theta-30^\circ)}}{\frac{\sin (\theta+120^\circ)}{\cos (\theta+120^\circ)}-\frac{\sin (\theta-30^\circ)}{\cos (\theta-30^\circ)}}=\frac{m+n}{m-n}$$

Then you have, $$\frac{\frac{\sin (\theta+120^\circ)\cos (\theta-30^\circ)+\cos (\theta+120^\circ)\sin (\theta-30^\circ)}{\cos (\theta+120^\circ)\cos (\theta-30^\circ)}}{\frac{\sin (\theta+120^\circ)\cos (\theta-30^\circ)-\cos (\theta+120^\circ)\sin (\theta-30^\circ)}{\cos (\theta+120^\circ)\cos (\theta-30^\circ)}}=\frac{m+n}{m-n}$$

The denominators cancel out to again give you
$$\frac{\sin (\theta+120^\circ)\cos (\theta-30^\circ)+\cos (\theta+120^\circ)\sin (\theta-30^\circ)}{\sin (\theta+120^\circ)\cos (\theta-30^\circ)-\cos (\theta+120^\circ)\sin (\theta-30^\circ)}=\frac{m+n}{m-n}$$

$$\frac{\sin (2\theta + 90^\circ)}{\sin 150^\circ}=\frac{m+n}{m-n}$$

Can you complete the rest now?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Expressing $\tan$ as $\dfrac\sin\cos$ will be more easier, right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Do you mean from the step where I have left off? Yes surely. That's the best trick to do it.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat, Using $Tan120=-√3$ and $Tan30=\frac{1}{√3}$ and then using the compound angle formula for $Tan$, it becomes very complex..

Comment: @Iaamuseruser Don't use compound angle formula for $\tan$. Do what lab bhattacharjee has commented. From the step where I have left, break $\tan$ into $\sin$ and $\cos$. And then simplify. I am updating my answer.

Comment: @Iaamuseruser Please check my edit. I have updated it properly.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat, yes its helpful and I have completed..

Comment: @SchrodingersCat, The division of $\tan$ as $$\dfrac\sin\cos$$ should ideally be done even before applying Componendo-Dividendo,

Answer (score 1):

$\tan(\theta +120)$ = -$\cot(\theta +30)$  = - $1\over {\tan(\theta +30)}$
From this we get 
$$\tan(30-\theta) * \tan(30+\theta) $$ = $n\over m$

Expand and proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use $$\tan(a\pm b)=\frac{\tan(a)\pm \tan(b)}{1 \mp \tan(a)\tan(b)}$$ ie if $a+b$ then denominator has $-$ve sign  and vice-versa, then $\cos 2x=\frac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}$ to get the result.