# If $m \tan(\theta - \pi/6) = n \tan(\theta + 2\pi/3)$ then find $\cos 2\theta$

Tags: trigonometry

If $$m \tan(\theta - \pi/6) = n \tan(\theta + 2\pi/3)$$
then find $\cos 2\theta$ in terms of $m$ and $n$.
What is the correct method to solve this question?

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Also, if do remember that Mathematics is not a pursuit for an easy method, but one that gives the most truest of outcomes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that $m\tan (\theta-30°)=n\tan (\theta+120°)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1644430/prove-that-m-tan-theta-30-n-tan-theta120)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\dfrac{\sin\left(\theta-\dfrac\pi6\right)\cos\left(\theta+\dfrac{2\pi}3\right)}{\cos\left(\theta-\dfrac\pi6\right)\sin\left(\theta+\dfrac{2\pi}3\right)}=\dfrac nm$$

Using  [Componendo and Dividendo](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/) and $\sin(A\pm B)$ [formulae](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html),

$$\dfrac{m-n}{m+n}=\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi}3+\dfrac\pi6\right)}{\sin\left(2\theta+\dfrac{2\pi}3-\dfrac\pi6\right)}=\dfrac{\dfrac12}{\cos2\theta}$$ as $\sin\left(\dfrac{5\pi}6\right)=\sin\left(\pi-\dfrac\pi6\right)=\sin\dfrac\pi6=?$

and $\sin\left(A+\dfrac\pi2\right)=\cos A$

Comment: Wish I know the mistake here that has caused the downvote

Comment: +1 Looks good to me! Certainly gives the right answer for $m/n=1,2,3$.

Comment: @almagest, Thanks for confirmation :) Not the toughest solution, right?

Answer (score 3):

$$m\left( \frac{\tan \theta -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}}{1+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\tan \theta } \right)=n\left( \frac{\tan \theta -\sqrt{3}}{1+\sqrt{3}\tan \theta } \right)\,\,\,\,\Rightarrow \,\,\,{{\tan }^{2}}\theta =\frac{m-3n}{3m-n}$$
Now apply this identity
$$\cos 2\theta =\frac{1-{{\tan }^{2}}\theta }{1+{{\tan }^{2}}\theta }$$

Comment: There must be a mistake somewhere here. Put $m=3n$. Then the original equation has solution $\theta=n\pi$ or $\tan\theta=0$. But you get $\tan\theta=0.75$.

Comment: I will check it

Comment: Looks like it should be $\tan^2\theta=\frac{m-3n}{3m-n}$.

Comment: thanks. I checked it several times.  Are you sure?

Comment: you are right. so thanks